# Flask-Security: how to set up the database outside the main py file?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm using Flask-Security 1.7.4 together with Flask 0.10.1.

I have no problem running my website if the database scheme is stored in the python file `app.py`:

```
from flask.ext.security import RoleMixin, UserMixin, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, Security
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

#Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    companyid = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

However I would like to separate more my code so I can have:

```
app_folder
|__ app.py  # Main file for the app
|__ security.py  # File that contain the database for the login/roles
```

So I tried:

in `security.py`:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()  

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table(
        'roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    companyid = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
```

And in `app.py`:

```
from flask.ext.security import RoleMixin, UserMixin, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, Security
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from security import db, user_datastore 

app = Flask(__name__)

#Initiate the database connection object
db.init_app(app)

# Setup Flask-Security
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
File "C:\Work\pythonVirtualEnv\env02\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 436, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: users u'SELECT users.user_id AS users_user_id, users.username AS users_username, users.password AS users_password, users.email AS users_email, users.registered_on AS users_registered_on \nFROM users \nWHERE users.password = ? AND users.email = ?\n LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' (u'test', u'demo@demo.com', 1, 0)
```

The things is, if I keep all the code in `app.py` it works flawlessly. 
And of course the database to exists.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different structure (and the advised one):

```
proj_folder
- run.py
- config.py
|__ app  # Main folder for the app
|__ __init__.py
|__ models.py
|__ security.py
|__ views.py
```

On models you keep your app models
On security you keep your security models
On views you create your views and expose your urls

Then on **init**.py

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.appbuilder import SQLA
from flask.ext.appbuilder import AppBuilder
from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app import models, security, views
```

On run.py

```
from app import app

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Hope this helps

Take a look at https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder-Skeleton

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it gives the same error message. I think the db is not initialized correctly but I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you have a user table on the db?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. It works fine if I put all the code in the main py file.